# error: specializing member '<program specific expression>' requires 'template<>' syntax

Tags: c++, templates

```
#ifndef HARDWARE_HPP
#define HARDWARE_HPP
#include <modm/platform.hpp>

using namespace modm::platform;

namespace Board
{
  using Pin = GpioC4;
  using OneWireMaster = BitBangOneWireMaster<Pin>;
  OneWireMaster::connect<Pin::BitBang>();
}
#endif  // HARDWARE_HPP
```

I get following:

```
error: specializing member 'modm::platform::BitBangOneWireMaster<modm::platform::GpioC4>::connect<modm::platform::GpioC4::BitBang>' requires 'template<>' syntax
```

But if I take this definition to main.cpp this works perfectly fine.
Any help?

Comment: Show the code that works perfectly fine.

Comment: I found that if you do this in any .cpp file it works fine, only doing it in hpp creates this problem.